# Delegate "Read" Ability to GPO's

Tags: group-policy, delegation, read-only

Is there a way to allow a non-administrator to "read" (as in browse and look at the settings) of domain gpo's?

I see in GPMC there is an option to allow delegation of "Read Group Policy Results data" but I'm not solid on whether that will provide the type of access requested.  Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've check gpo read permissions. I'm use [gpmc.msc](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0A6D4C24-8CBD-4B35-9272-DD3CBFC81887&displaylang=en) tool for grant permission. There is a Delegation tab under the each GP object. I think that is the place, where you need to grant permissions.

But by default Authenticated users has read access for all GP objects, i.e. all users in whole AD forest and trusted domains have read access.

Comment: Thanks.  The latter part of your answer is what is what I was looking for.  I looked at the delegation option but decided that for this purpose it wasn't a good fit.